# Hover and change image

Tags: blazor

I am trying to make a website with blazor and want to have an image that shows part of a larger photo, and if someone hovers over it for 3-5 seconds it'll scale up but be a different image. I would guess there might be a tooltip or something that would be helpful, but not sure with the hover causing a different image all together.

Comment: This is not about and specific to Blazor. you will just need to find a javascript library that has this functionality and use it with Blazor.

Answer (score 4):

It's not really *Blazor* specific, it's something that can be done with ***CSS***.

It's not very clear what you mean with *"..an image that shows part of a larger photo.."*

This example shows how you can hover over an image where the image will scale up and then change after some time.

Add some *css* to your style sheet file:

```
.default-image {
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-image: url('/images/Cap1.png');    
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.hovering {
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-image: url('/images/Cap1.png');
    transform: scale(2.0);
}

    .hovering:hover {
        transition-delay: 1s;
        transition-duration: 0s;           
        background-image: url('/images/Cap2.png');        
    }
```

Then add a `<div>` that contains the default image and another `<div>` that will show the changed image.

You can use the `@onmouseover` and `@onmouseout` events. (and possibly the `@ontouchenter` and `@ontouchleave`)

```
<div class="default-image"
     @onmouseout="@OnMouseOut"
     @onmouseover="@OnMouseOver">
    <div class="@_HoverImageCSSClass">
        @*this will be used for the transformed image*@
    </div>
</div>

@code {

    bool _IsHovering = false;
    string _HoverImageCSSClass = "";

    protected void OnMouseOver(MouseEventArgs mouseEvent)
    {
        if (!_IsHovering)
        {
            _IsHovering = true;
            _HoverImageCSSClass = "hovering";
            StateHasChanged();
        }
    }

    protected void OnMouseOut(MouseEventArgs mouseEvent)
    {
        _HoverImageCSSClass = "";
        _IsHovering = false;
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

I used the `_IsHovering` variable so that the class is only set once when the mouse is moving within the image.

The `transition-delay` is 1 second and `transition-duration` is 0, but this can obviously be changed to your needs.

This will give you this effect:

[image: ImageChangeAfterDelay]